# What is this red warning I'm seeing on Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm seeing a red warning in Google Play Console, in "Publishing Overview"
[image]
But I did complete "Data safety" form (some weeks ago)
[image]
What is this about?

Answer (score -1):

[check](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/10/launching-data-safety-in-play-console.html) this and follow the instruction carefully.

Comment: So much text + page after page, link after link.. I just need to know if my app is in trouble. Note: that I did completed the Data safety form..

Comment: your app not in trouble. if you complete data safety form that fine, you will get update soon check.

Comment: Your answer is effectively just one link. Please do at least quote the relevant parts of the linked page best with a short summary created by you.